# Kivy: Label has another position then Rectangle

Tags: python, kivy

I'm really new to Kivy and I'm trying to position some text on a canvas, but I found that the `Label` I'm using isn't positioned properly. If I'm drawing a `Rectangle` with the same values it has the right position.

I found some similar questions here but I think there was no answer for me.

Here's my code:

```
class MyClass(Widget):

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(MyClass, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self._keyboard = Window.request_keyboard(self._keyboard_closed, self)
        self._keyboard.bind(on_key_down=self._on_keyboard_down)

    def _keyboard_closed(self):
        pass

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        with self.canvas:   
            lbl_staticText = Label(font_size=12)       
            lbl_staticText.text = 'This is some nice random text\nwith linebreak'
            lbl_staticText.texture_update()
            textSize = lbl_staticText.texture_size
            Rectangle(pos=(1024/2 - textSize[0]/2, 600), size=(textSize[0], textSize[1])); #Rectangle with same position and same size
            lbl_staticText.pos = (1024/2 - textSize[0]/2, 600)
```

The result looks like:

[image]

As you can see the `Rectangle` position is horizontally centered as expected but the `Label` is neither centered nor has the right height position.

Please can you tell me why there is a difference?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, you forgot to check for the size of the label that's first of all. The default one is always `[100, 100]`. You didn't add the `Label` anywhere as a child, therefore it ignores `size_hint` which is by default set to `[1, 1]`.

The end result:

- `Label` widget area is `[100, 100]`
- `Label` texture is `[something, something]` (for me that's `[160, 32]`)

Now you create a `Rectangle` with size of the `Label`'s texture size and place it somewhere, then you move the `Label` to align it. Their sizes are different.

Uncomment the last commented line to see the difference.

```
class MyClass(Widget):
    ...

    def _on_keyboard_down(self, keyboard, keycode, text, modifiers):
        with self.canvas:
            lbl_staticText = Label(font_size=12)       
            lbl_staticText.text = 'This is some nice random text\nwith linebreak'
            lbl_staticText.texture_update()
            textSize = lbl_staticText.texture_size

            Color(1, 0, 0, 1)
            Rectangle(
                pos=(100+textSize[0]/2.0, 100),
                size=(textSize[0], textSize[1])
            )
            lbl_staticText.pos = (100+textSize[0]/2.0, 300)
            print(lbl_staticText.size, textSize, lbl_staticText.size == textSize)
            #lbl_staticText.size=(textSize[0], textSize[1])  # this!
            Color(0, 1, 0, 1)
            Rectangle(
                pos=lbl_staticText.pos,
                size=lbl_staticText.size
            )

runTouchApp(MyClass())
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. OK, I didn't know that the texture_size differs from the label.size. I think thats the point I miss. You mentioned the size_hint. What's the matter with it with view to the problem? I didn't get the context to the problem.

Comment: @S-Man Look at [`Label.texture_size`](https://kivy.org/docs/api-kivy.uix.label.html#kivy.uix.label.Label.texture_size) to see what's going on. About the `size_hint`, well, a widget works with those values if it's added into a parent that can work with those values (mainly layouts). You created the `Label` as a completely separate Python object while drawing to the `canvas` of `MyClass`, therefore no parent = no `size_hint` used.